# Does dismissing a Forsaken Master remove the workbench you recieved from them?

Tags: path-of-exile

As you know, Forsaken Masters give you a workbench that you can place into your hideout and use after talking to them in your hideout, once you invite them into it. Also, there is the ability to dismiss a master.

From what I know, dismissing a master only resets your progress to the next "Master" level back to 0... However, does it remove (take back) the workbench it has given you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it stays there so you still get the benefits of it up to the level of the dismissed master. One of my characters has all of them and I just switch the actual masters out when I want to level particular ones up.